# C# mono: start bash process without exiting

Tags: c#, linux, bash, mono

I am trying to start a bash (shell) process (like a new console window, but without user interface) from my C# program (mono/linux). I want to let this process run (until my program decides to stop it).

However, if I run bash like this, it will run and exit (immediately):

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"&> {outputFile}";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; 

p.Start();

//keeping a reference to p, to interact with bash later-on
```

Comment: `&> {outputFile}` looks like a redirection but redirections don't work when passed as arguments. unless you have a file named `&> ...` it's expected behavior for bash to exit immediately

Comment: Thanks @ogus ismail for your quick response. I do not fully understand your comment, The reason that I try to redirect all output to a file is that I use a separate task that is reading the contents of that file, being able to display output without waiting for the process to send a EOL.
Any suggestions on how to start the bash process, configuring it to output (immediately/continuously) and let the process run (being able to receive commands on the input stream)?

Comment: What @oguzismail is saying is: `&>...` is not supposed to be an argument to `bash` process. It's input/output/error redirection. Do not treat it like arguments. You should setup the stdout and stderr separately before launching the process (bash in this case). As a workaround, you can launch bash with arguments like this: `-c bash &>{outputFile}`. This will launch bash and that bash will internally launch `bash &>{outputFile}` And this time, the redirection will be interpreted by the parent bash that you launched.

Answer (score 0):

Add the next line:

`p.WaitForExit();`

This will take care that your programm will wait for the proces to exit.

Comment: Hi Raimond, do you suggest that the WaitForExit() call will prevent the bash from exiting immediately?